Late correction or regulation on llm result
LLM chat window screenshot
I have seen this more than once in LLM models. Recently started experimenting with llama2.
I observe that the model gives a results and then later realises that it might have been inappropriate, and then corrects itself rather than not giving incorrect/ inappropriate answer in the first place.
What is this phenomenon called, why does it happen and how could it be fixed?
Had set model temperature to 1, and gave a brief intro mentioning my name as description under SYSTEM.
